# Retrieve jQuery Cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Example, I have this cookie:

```
$.cookie("foo", "500", { path: '/', expires: 365 });
```

How do I get the value of that cookie and put it into a variable?

For example (I know this is not correct):

```
var foo = $.cookie("foo").val();
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's just `var foo = $.cookie("foo")`.

There's no need for a `.val()` call as you're not accessing the *value* of a DOM element.

Comment: Damn, I had that before turns out I was using the wrong cookie!

Comment: ball , out of context question , is this plugin support dictionary also.

Comment: @kobe I do not understand what you are asking. Consider asking a separate question, or just experiment with the plugin yourself.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```js
function getCookieValue(cname) { 
    // cname is the cookie name (foo) which value you are after
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of a cookie, you can just call it's reference. For example:

```
$.cookie("foo", "somevalue");
alert($.cookie("foo"));
```

Will alert:

```
somevalue
```

Comment: How would you alert the 'expires' property?

Answer (score 2):

By this way we can access

`console.log($.cookie());` //It will gives the all cookies in the form of object

`alert($.cookie('foo'));`//it will give cookie foo value ie `500`