# Cookies and Javascript addition ? (parseInt)

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I am working on some cookies script which my cookieA (name of cookie) is null (contains nothing).

When a button is clicked, this script will add 10 to the value of cookieA. And when I click the button again, the value 10 will become 20 and so on.

Here's the script :

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $.cookie(cookieA, parseInt($.cookie(cookieA).val(),10) +10 , cookieOptions);
});
```

Please help me, this is making the value turn into NaN or null .

Thanks and have a wonderful day.

p/s I'm using the script from Klaus Hartly the author of jQuery cookies.

p/s Cookieopstions is the settings for the cookies expiry date etc.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add 10 to the value of the cookie if the cookie is not null ? or are your trying to add 10 to nothing ?

Maybe you could check your cookie first ?

```
If ($.cookie(cookieA) == null) {
   $.cookie(cookieA, 10, cookieOptions);
} Else {
   $.cookie(cookieA, parseInt($.cookie(cookieA).val(),10) +10 , cookieOptions);
}
```

If i did not understand your question, please let me know,

Regards,

Max

Comment: No , when the button is clicked , it will add 10 to the current existing number . for example , when its null it adds then and it becomes 10 , and when i click the button again it will become 20 .

Comment: So what do you get when you debug ? did you try to get each value separately ? Btw, seems like you shouldn't use `val()` to get the value : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171865/retrieve-jquery-cookie-value