# Have Checkbox Stay Checked Throughout Session

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, session-storage

I have a table where I can check a checkbox and it will log all of the contents in the row. There are some search functions and other buttons on the page, so I want to use session storage to be able to keep any checkboxes that are checked, checked, throughout refreshes until the page is closed. I have something from an example I found but it doesnt seem to be working. How could I fix this?

HTML for table column/row with checkboxes:

```
<td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check" id="checkid"></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var test = sessionStorage.input === 'false'? true: false;
    $('input').prop('checked', test || false);

    $('input').on('change', function() {
    sessionStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve jQuery Cookie value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171865/retrieve-jquery-cookie-value)

Comment: Not sure...I made an edit...is that how it should look now?

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Thy and find out :)

Comment: It will log the value "true" now but it wont keep any checkboxes checked after refresh

Comment: It seems like the ternary for the test variable is backwards.  EDIT: and as is, the test would never be null so the || false part is weird. EDIT2: and you can just do `this.checked = true/false'`, you don't have to go through jquery to access that object property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
var test = sessionStorage.input === 'false'? true: false;
```

So what does it mean? If `sessionStorage.input` is **false**, return **true**, else **false**.

So when you check the checkbox then it's set to **true**, which by the above logic, since it's not **false** -  test is evaluated as `false`.

Solution:

```
var test = sessionStorage.input === 'true';
```

This will set test to `true` if the session is also **true**.

You can also change `$('input').prop('checked', test || false);` to:

```
$('input').prop('checked', test);
```

The `|| false` is unnecessary. Or even better/shorter:

```
$('input').prop('checked', sessionStorage.input === 'true');
```

And then you don't need the `test` variable at all.

As for your question *"how can I make this work for individual checkboxes"*: You can use the checkbox `id` for example:

```
// save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
// using the checkbox "id" attribute
var $el = $(this);
sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
```

And then, when you refresh the page:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
});
```

So this is how it should look like:

```
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        // Iterate over the checkboxes and set their "check" values based on the session data
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
    });

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        // save the individual checkbox in the session inside the `change` event, 
        // using the checkbox "id" attribute
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
    });
});
```

[Working solution](https://jsfiddle.net/uskuxpm1/) - Couldn't use stack-snippets because it doesn't support `sessionStorage` due to security limitations.

Comment: Okay sweet! This seems to work! Only other question is how can I make this work for individual checkboxes? Right now, if I select one or unselect one, it selects/unselects all of them

Comment: I updated my JS code to what I have now using your code...let me know if it is placed right because right now im still having the issue

Comment: @Rataiczak24 No - Take `$(':checkbox').each(function() { .... })` and replace it with `var test = sessionStorage.input === 'true';` and the next line (`$('input').prop('checked', test);`)

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Also change `essionStorage[$el.prop('checkid')] = $el.is(':checked');` with `sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');`

Comment: Okay, still not working...updated my JS again to make sure we are on the same page

Comment: @Rataiczak24 Do you have a **unique ID** for each checkbox in the page?

Comment: @Rataiczak24 So please make sure you have, then it should work. Note that I changed `:checkbox` to `input:checkbox` - It's better that way

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rataiczak24 You're welcome `:)` Can I revert your question to the original question you posted without the parts from my answer, so other users can see what was wrong and learn from it

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks